# Proving that non-zero vectors are linearly independent given a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I am having difficulty approaching this problem (below), I think it requires to construct $3x3$ matrices then using Gauss-Jordan Elimination to using the get the RREF. Although, I  believe I am missing some steps. Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

> If C is a $3×3$ matrix and if the non-zero vectors $u$ and $v ∈ R^{3}$ are such that
>
> $$Cu = 2u\ and \ Cv = −5v$$
>
> show that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they were linearly dependent, then there would be a $\lambda\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $v=\lambda u$. Now, find a contradiction between this and what you know about $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Nice answer! I think your way is a little easier than mine, but I’ll leave mine up as I generally like the direct approach :) +$1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** start with $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$ for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in F$ and apply $C$ to both sides. Use the facts about $Cu$ and $Cv$ to help conclude $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$.

Comment: Umm... $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ always satisfies your equation. I suspect that you meant that one must show that this is the _only_ solution.

Comment: @amd: the point is that if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ satisfy the equation, then we **must have** $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$. This is the definition of linear independence. That is, what I have typed is precisely what I mean.

Comment: That’s not what you wrote, though. You’re missing a key phrase that’s part of the definition of linear independence you purportto be using.

Comment: @amd: not at all. I have written “start with $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$ for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in F$” and am making no assumptions on $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$. Later, we “conclude $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$.” This is the definition of linear independence.

Comment: No, it’s not. The definition of linear independence requires that the **only** linear combination that vanishes has $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$. That might be what you meant in your answer, but that’s not at all what it actually says. That one little word makes all the difference.

Comment: @amd: it is **exactly equivalent** to say that if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ satisfy the equation $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$ implies $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$, then the solution is unique. This is because we are proving that the only solution is given by $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ (how else could we conclude that we must have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ unless no other solutions exist?). Again, just to reiterate: we are assuming that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ satisfy the linear combination. Then we prove that we have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$. It **immediately** follows that this is the only possible combination.

Comment: @amd: Let me try to explain the hint a little more thoroughly for you... the hint aims to aid the OP in proving that if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in F$ satisfy $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$, then we must have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$. This is obviously enough to imply that the only solution to $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$ is the trivial solution, thereby establishing the linear independence of $u$ and $v$. This is precisely why I've started with the general equation $\alpha_1u+\alpha_2v=\bar0$ and provide steps to prove that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$; we **cannot** have any other solutions (and it's a hint...)